# How can I order all subcategories alphabetical independent of the parent categories?

Tags: categories, loop, order

These are my hierarchical three level categories:

```markdown
- Top-Level Cat 1
  - Sub1A
    - Subchild1A1
    - Subchild1A2
  - Sub1B
    - Subchild1B1
    - Subchild1B2
- Top-Level Cat 2
  - Sub2A
    - Subchild2A1
    - Subchild2A2
  - Sub2B
    - Subchild2B1
    - Subchild2B2
...
```

Is it possible to get all bottom level category names (the subchildren) and sort them alphabetically independent of the parents? I get all subchildren categories, but they are only orderer alphabetical inside their top level category.

For example I get

```
Bosnia
Sweden
Congo
Southafrica
```

From the top level categories `Europe` and `Africa`.

But I want to get:

```
Bosnia
Congo
Southafrica
Sweden
```

Edit: This is the way I get the First child categories:

```php
<?php
    //Get All Categories like Parent, parent of child, child of subchild (Level 0 , 1, 2)
    $taxonomy = 'category'; //Choose the taxonomy
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy ); //Get all the terms

    foreach ($terms as $term) { //Cycle through terms, one at a time

    // Check and see if the term is a top-level parent. If so, display it.
    $parent = $term->parent;
    if ( $parent=='0' ) {

        $term_id = $term->term_id; //Define the term ID
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy ); //Get the link to the archive page for that term
        $term_name = $term->name;
            $childargs = array('parent' => $term_id, 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', );
            $childcategories = get_terms( 'category',$childargs );
            foreach($childcategories as $childcategory) {
                $childterm_id = $childcategory->term_id;
                echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $childcategory->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $childcategory->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $childcategory->name.'</a></li>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: How are you getting and sorting the subcategories at the moment?

Comment: @Rup I've added my code for geting all first level categories